# Is the borel $\sigma$-algebra over reals a complete lattice?

Tags: lattice-orders, borel-sets

I've read in [some forum answer](http://at.yorku.ca/cgi-bin/bbqa?forum=ask_an_analyst_2012&task=show_msg&msg=4038.0002) that "the Borel sigma-algebra on the real numbers $\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$ is not a complete lattice" and I was wondering why and hope you can help.

**Def.** a *complete lattice* is a partially ordered set in which all subsets have both a supremum (join) and an infimum (meet).

**Def.** The Borel $\sigma$-algebra on the reals is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra that contains all the open sets

One way for the above statement to hold would be if $[-\infty,\infty] \notin \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$ -is this the case and why?
*I would have guessed that $[-\infty,\infty] \in \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$; because $\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$ is closed under countable union and all open and closed sets exist in it, thus, $(0,1),[1,2]\in \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})\Rightarrow [-\infty,1),[1,\infty]\in \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}) \Rightarrow [-\infty,\infty]\in \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$.*

PS: I hope the tags are correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that every singleton is a Borel set in the case of $\Bbb R$. So for the Borel sets to form a complete lattice, any collection of singletons must have a join.

In other words, it would require every set of reals to be a Borel set. Since this is certainly not the case (at least under the standard assumptions of the axiom of choice), it follows that the Borel algebra is not a complete lattice.

Comment: There are $\mathfrak{c}$ many Borel sets (does this depend on choice?) and $2^\mathfrak{c}$ many subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ so counting gives us non-Borel sets already.

Comment: @Henno: If $\Bbb R$ is a countable union of countable sets, then every set is Borel.

Comment: You write "In other words, it would require every set of reals to be a Borel set".  That seems an oversimplification. For a sublattice to be a complete lattice, it is not necessary that it is a complete sublattice. (in the sense that the infinite joins must all be the same) E.g. the closed sets do form a complete lattice.

Comment: @Niels: Yeah, okay, I see what you mean there. But if a set has a smallest Borel superset, then it has to be equal to that set. Proof: simply remove one point.

Comment: So this could be formulated as: Every singleton set of $\mathbb{R}$ exists in $\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$. In order for $\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$ to form a complete lattice, any collection of singletons must have a join. This is not true for a set containing all but one of the singletons, e.g. $\{\{r\} \mid r \in \mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}\} \notin \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: @Kirkeby: No. Every singleton is Borel, so every complement of a singleton is Borel. What Niels pointed out, and correctly so, is that a complete lattice $A$ can be a sublattice of a complete lattice $B$, but not a complete sublattice of $B$. In retort, I pointed out that in such case, that would imply that for any set of reals there is a minimal Borel set which contains it, which is not true exactly because the singletons are Borel, so by removing one point from the set we have a strictly smaller Borel set, so if we have a minimal Borel superset, it has to be the set itself.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thanks for the response -it helped.